# PDFsharp: Reference to type 'FontFamily' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could be found

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I'm using [PDFsharp 1.50rc2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp/1.50.4845-RC2a) in my web application (ASP.NET Core 2) to generate PDF.
I already follow the [example](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloWorld-sample.ashx) on the PDFsharp site. But got problem to generate it, probably related to the FontFamily in the System.Drawing. Not sure. Below is my code to generate the PDF.

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller {
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      // creating the PDF
      CreatePDF();

      return View();
    }

    public void CreatePDF()
    {
      // Create a new PDF document
      PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
      document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

      // Create an empty page
      PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

      // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
      XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

      // Create a font
      // PROBLEM IN HERE (new XFONT)
      XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

      // Draw the text
      gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
      new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
      XStringFormats.Center);

      // Save the document...
      const string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";
      document.Save(filename);
      // ...and start a viewer.
      Process.Start(filename);
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**

> Reference to type 'FontFamily' claims it is defined in
>   'System.Drawing', but it could be found

Comment: No MCVE, not detailed information. The cause of the problem is probably outside the snippet shown here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a version of PDFsharp that relies on GDI+ and your project may have to reference `System.Drawing` e.g. when you need fonts, pens, brushes, and such.

To avoid references to GDI+, you can use the WPF build of PDFsharp:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp-wpf/1.50.4845-RC2a

When using the WPF build you also have to add references to WPF when it comes to using fonts, pens, brushes, &c.
You need a reference to `PresentationCore` for the WPF build.

PDFsharp 1.50 was not designed to work with .NET Core and may not work on other platforms than Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by add references to WPF? I already install the WPF, where can I find the example on this? I found this site but doesn't have the sample code Hello World in there. https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp-samples/tree/master/samples

Comment: @saf21 Open the sample solution with VS and you will see all the source code. And then you can also see the references added to each project. You need a reference to `PresentationCore` for the WPF build.

Comment: Or you can use Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

Comment: There is a Nuget package named PDFSharp.netstandard. I haven't tested it straight yet, but using it instead of the normal PdfSharp package, the error gone...
here's the repo from it https://github.com/jmanm/PDFsharp-netstandard2.0/
It's for NET Standard, it should but I don't know if it works in other kinds of project either.

Comment: As of september 2022, there is now a `PDFSharp.NetStandard2`, which has dependencies in `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 4.5.0` and `System.Drawing.Common 4.5.0`. Just used it in Linqpag 7.0 with NET 6.0.9.

Answer (score -2):

I found the 2nd parameter of the XFont class
needed to be a float type and not an int

```
// force a float value
let font1 = new XFont("arial", 12.0, XFontStyle.Bold)
```

once corrected the compiler error disappeared

Comment: Is that VB.NET code? The C# compiler automatically casts `int` to `float` and appending `.0` is not required.

Comment: its F# code I could have used the suffix f making 12f I guess

Comment: The question is about C# and I don't see any relevance of your F# answer for the original C# problem. Did you get the same compiler error as shown in the first post? If adding ".0" resolved the issue then you probably got a different error message or made other changes as well.

Comment: as F# shares the same .net ecosystem as C# the answer is highly relevant, this library (pdfSharp) is not exclusively C#, if it was it may be called pdfCSharp ! I simply found the user had the wrong "type" in the parameter list nothing more, the language was irrelevant. The fix is all that mattered. pdfSharp was a good fit for me i'm happily generating invoices for my clients in production.

Comment: Highly relevant answers will receive many upvotes. PDFsharp is called PDfsharp because it was written in C# - the only "sharp" language at that time. There is one .NET ecosystem, but VB.NET or F# sometimes require explicit casts where C# casts implicitly. You did not answer: Did you get exactly the error message from the original post?